# How to replace an int value in String and adjust field length

Tags: javascript, html, replace, str-replace

I have like 120 img in HTML, that are loaded properly with Javascript when click event occurs.

Then i get the attribute "src" from the img and store it in `var currentModalImg_src`.

For example, i receive the image number 10, and i have this string :

```
    var currentModalImg_src = "img/reclamos-sinaleticas/Full/f(10).jpg";
```

Then i extract only the number and store it in this variable: `var imgSrcNumber`

Then i decrement that value by 1 and replace the string with that value.

But with this code:

```
     currentModalImg_src = currentModalImg_src.replace( /\d/g, imgSrcNumber-1);
```

Im getting this (it's replacing the two digits):

```
img/reclamos-sinaleticas/Full/f(99).jpg
```

**The result i want is this :**

```
    `var currentModalImg_src = "img/reclamos-sinaleticas/Full/f(9).jpg";
```

*For numbers like 8 or 23 (examples) works fine, the problem is when it's 10 or 100 for example.*

Is there an efficient way solve this?
Thanks for your attenttion.

Comment: Use `/\d+/g` as expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only replace one digit with a specific value, you need to `replace` the entire number (*10*, *23* or *100*) with the specific value.

Replace `\d` with `\d+`

```
 currentModalImg_src = currentModalImg_src.replace( /\d+/g, imgSrcNumber-1);
```